# JSON Data to .NET Class

Tags: .net, json, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I'm just writing some conversion code for the Facebook friend objects and I tried using the [json2csharp converter](http://json2csharp.com/) and it seems to create a lot of classes in order to provide the structure.

**JSON**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Name1",
      "id": "34535345",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fiamge.jpg",
          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Name2",
      "id": "23424234",
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fimage.jpg",
          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }
    }]
}
```

**CSharp json2csharp**

```
public class Data
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool is_silhouette { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Picture picture { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Seems to be a lot of classes for a fairly simple piece of JSON.  Is there a way to get around the need for the Picture -> Data relationship and just have the Picture class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and `dynamic`

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynObj.data)
    Console.WriteLine(item.picture.data.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems like just the right amount of classes for the JSON you supplied. The `Picture` and `Data` classes represent the JSON as it is. Is there any specific reason why this bothers you?

Comment: Just that as the graph grows there are going to potentially be a lot of classes that don't really do much.  Consdering you can name the `DataMembers` it would be good if the `DataContract` behaved in the same manner.  I was wondering if there was a way to do that but after trying it doesn't appear to work that way.

Comment: Why do you care about the amount of classes? The compiler will handle it.